# nginx reverse proxy location

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I would like to have nginx set as a reverse proxy following these rules:

```
http://www.example.com/home/{x}/{y}//index.html?zvalue={z}&a=1&b=2&c=3 etc...
```

proxied to

```
http://www.example2.com/home/{x}/{y}/{z}/index.html?a=1&b=2&c=3 etc...
```

So basically the query string value of {z} is set as part of the path.
All other query params such as a,b,c,d etc need to be forwarded as shown in the example.

What are the configuration I need to put in nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating the query string is best done using a `map` with named captures. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

For example:

```
map $request_uri $proxy {
    default 0;
    ~*^(?<prefix>/home/.*)/index.html\?zvalue=(?<zvalue>[^&]+)&(?<suffix>.*)$ $prefix/$zvalue/index.html?$suffix;
}
```

Obviously the regular expression needs to match your exact requirements, and the above was just a proof of concept.

You can use the variable with a `proxy_pass` statement, within an `if` block, within an existing `location`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

For example:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://example.com;
    if ($proxy) { proxy_pass http://example.com$proxy; }
}
```

Any request which is not subject to the `map` will be passed transparently by the first `proxy_pass` statement.